# Site design: 404/captcha/error page images

Tags: discussion, design

I'll be presenting community with the final design of rpg.se very soon. Meanwhile, I need some ideas for the [error](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/error), [captcha](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/captcha) and [404](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/404)  page images.

For the captcha image, I normally use a non-human figure and keep it light hearted. For the this site's catpcha image, I'm thinking about using a group shot of action figures from various games, golems, cyborgs etc.

Please post your ideas here, preferably with photo references.

Comment: ok, i'll stop with the suggestions now

Answer (score 19):

#### Suggestion "404"

> *"What a roll!*"

[image]

(own horrible picture, own horrible image manipulation :P )

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Failure! (and it was only DC 5!)

Answer (score 12):

404: A d20 on a 1 saying "Critical failure!"

Like this, but a cleaner die
[image: d20]

Comment: Best suggestion!  I like it more for an error page though, with the 404 dice for the 404. And really it can be an ornate die like this because it can be large - certainly no smaller than this... B&W should make the image size small.

Comment: @mxyzplk: Isn't that a little too D&D/d20 specific? Why not 3d6 showing all 6s? Or 3d10 showing all 10s? Or 3d20 showing all 20? Or d12+d10+d8 showing all 1s?

Comment: I think 3 dice of different sizes showing 4 0 4 would be a bit better

Comment: @PatLudwig: That's actually a very nice idea! :D

Comment: Nah, too D&D specific.

Comment: Because d20s are iconic to gaming. Even if you game of choice doesn't use them, you sure know them.

Comment: I'd have to agree that while it is d20 system-centric, way more people will know that a "1 on a d20 is a critical failure" than "3 sixes on a d6 means epic failure in...GURPS?", plus, 3 sixes in say Shadowrun is awesome, which is the opposite of what we want here.

Comment: @Cthos: but the d20 is also not universially used only in a way that means *"rolling high = good, rolling low = bad"*. I really like Pat's idea with different dice showing "4 0 4", perhaps a d20, a d10 and a d6 (D&D, WoD, SR).

Comment: @arotter - Can you name a game which uses the d20 wherein low = good? To follow that up, can you say that this game is known by more people in the general populace than D&D?

Comment: @Cthos: The Dark Eye, at least in previous editions. And also older D&D editions in some cases (saving throws in 2e IIRC, or some such).

Comment: @arotter - Okay, I'll give you The Dark Eye for Germany, but the older editions didn't make it into English according to Wikipedia, so... And yes, AD&D Saving throws were weird but THAC0 (the roll to hit things) still fumbled on a 1. That said I'm not opposed to a 404 made out of dice, but I do think the d20 critical fumble is pretty iconic.

Comment: Yeah, again, nothing is universal - but I think 99% of people would understand "natural 1 on d20 means bad - maybe not to the games I'm playing right now, but we get the idea". And it's neat and clever, which always overrides pickiness in my book.

Answer (score 7):

The 404 could be a wizard's spellbook or other tome, with the pages frantically flipping of their own accord. ("We can't seem to find that page…")

Comment: Oh yeah, a confused wizard looking in a big book, that would work!

Answer (score 6):

#### Suggestion "Captcha"

> *"Am I human?"*

[image]

(from [here](http://stormindacastle.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/race_modron.jpg))

Shown as an example, not expected to be used, due to copyright reasons.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure of the point of suggesting copyrighted images... We can't use it of course...

Comment: @mxyzplk Maybe could you just ask the copyright holder whether they would  allow us to use it? (Because it would really be great!)

Comment: @mxyzplk: Would you prefer me edition the (c) out? ;) The other pictures (e.g. the SR book cover, or the Cthulhu images) are surely copyrighted as well, yet you didn't seem to mind those. :P

Comment: Because I don't take the time to hassle every post doesn't mean it's not a valid point. I guess I could go mod crazy and just delete all the ones with copyrighted images.  Or you could explain what your intent is, which is I'm sure not using this exact image.

Comment: So, StackExchange is a for-profit company which has hired a professional artist/graphic designer to build the layout of the site. I had assumed that it went without saying that images are for reference/"this is what I'm talking about" purposes, and that Jin wasn't going to be using any of them directly. @mxyzplk

Comment: You also might want to explain what the heck a Modron is, and why it might be appropriate...

Comment: @AceCalhoon: I really appreciate the irony that you of all people chide me for **sarcastically** offering to remove the (c) line. It's ironic that you insist so much on me keeping the (c) and lecture me on copyright since you didn't even bother to mention where your own suggested image was from - the [cover picture of the *ShadowTech* supplement for 2nd edition Shadowrun](http://pl.shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowtech). So actually we can't use your picture either. Anyway, it's kinda sad that you all apparently desire to make a argument out of some creative brainstorming. :(

Comment: Sorry @arotter, missed the wink. Chiding redacted. Not sure what you mean by "we can't use it..." Like I said above, I assume Jin is making his own stuff (and won't be using anything here directly). Anyway, the important bit here is **why don't you explain why the Modran is cool, as Jin may not have heard of it**.

Answer (score 5):

For the captcha page, how about a very frustrated looking cyborg?

Possibly glaring at a computer screen of some kind, as though he'd just encountered the captcha page.

[image]

(via: http://drelb.free.fr/drelb41e.htm)

Comment: Hooray for ancient and obscure Shadowrun 2nd edition reference! :D

Answer (score 3):

Error:
a piece of paper (preferably a character sheet from something) with a glass of soda spileld on it.

So, something like this:

[image: character sheet]

plus something like this:

[image: spill]

Answer (score 3):

For the error I think we could have something like

"The Error has summoned Cthulhu/Shogoth!"
And then one of the picture below.

[image]
[image]

More HPL images welcome!

Comment: why'd you make this community wiki?

Comment: So others can add/remove similar images. Mine are all cthulhu mythos inspired but someone might have a better one.

Answer (score 1):

captcha: a troll caught in a net of some sort

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggestion "404"

> *"The world you are teleporting to could not be found."*

[image]

(from [here](http://eaae-astronomy.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/black-hole-swallows-star.jpg))

Comment: ehh, a little too sci-fi for me.  do yo have a game you're trying to reference?

Comment: @DForck42: so the whole site design should only include fantasy elements and completely disregard the bunch of sci-fi RPGs out there?

Comment: I'm not saying that all games are fantasy, it's just that any **game** reference in this is unknown, at least to me

Comment: @DForck42: Actually, that image is not from any specific game, which is what you probably want to know. I was just using it just to illustrate the idea of a black hole eating away a solar system. Black holes are used quite liberally in sci-fi, e.g. Stargate episode #38, the Maw in Star Wars, Transhuman Space, etc.

Comment: ahh.  i'll restate what i said, too sci-fi oriented and not **game** oriented enough for me ;)

Comment: @DForck42: Imho there is no such thing as "too sci-fi", especially not for a single page that only few people will see and since we know that in comparison a big effing dragon will be in the background of the final theme. There's a huge variety in RPGs and making the whole site appear fantasy-only could give the wrong impression to visitors (that horror/sci-fi/superhero games may not be welcome).

Comment: ... i don't have an issue with sci-fi, but the feel of this particular image is one of a movie or book about sci-fi instead of a role playing game about sci-fi, at least to me.  to reiterate, **there is no table top gaming aspect to your suggestion**, hence why i don't like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a robot on the captcha page, you might have a skeleton, zombie, frankenstein's monster or other assembled humanoid (or non-human) thing.

Comment: gelatinous cube?  ...i only know dnd....

Comment: @DForck42 Doesn't really look enough like a fake person, I'm afraid. It's a monster designed to fit in a square of graph paper. :)

Answer (score 1):

Reaper Mini sells minitures for table top games, both fantasy and SF. Their 404 page, 
http://www.reapermini.com/404.php, is not static but changes each time it is loaded. (OK, there is a limited number of pages from which is chosen.) I think it is at least worthwhile to have a look at the page (and reload a few times), and maybe we could have a changing 404 content at rpg.SE, too? This would allow for differently themed content, which would take into account different aspects of the site (for example SF and fantasy).

Answer (score -4):

#### Suggestion "Error"

> *"Something doesn't seem right here..."*

[image]

(from [here](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l6s6zusfEu1qa7t63o1_r1_500.jpg))